# SMPS mode power supply for 868 MHz operation in S2LP

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, transceiver, balun

I am trying to design a PCB for 868 MHz operations using S2LP, referring to the schematic from steval fki868v2. I have attached the same here. I would like to use SMPS mode and BALUN for the operation. I have 2 queries -

1. What shall be connected to PIN 3 (VSMPS2) and PIN 24 (VSMPS2)? Is it another power supply other than the VBattery?
2. If I am using the BALUN, then the filter circuit in the shown schematic for RXn and RXp shall be removed?

[image: Schematic for STEVAL FKI868V2]